# How to use mapply to apply a function to two different columns in two different data frames

Tags: r, function, mapply

I am trying to find duplicates between two columns across two different data frames. After identifying duplicates, I want to extract an observation from the same row the duplication was on, but from a different column, and insert it into the other data frame. Let me provide an example:

```
Table1:
tobecopied   B   Checkfordup   D
Copy1        2   dupchk1       5
Copy2        3   dupchk5       4
Copy3        4   dupchk4       K

Table2:
tobepastedinto   B   Checkfordup   D
                 5   dupchk1       L
                 6   dupchk2       M
                 7   dupchk4       3
```

So after the code runs, Table two will look like this:

```
Updated Table2:

tobepastedinto   B   Checkfordup   D
Copy1            5   dupchk1       L
                 6   dupchk2       M
Copy3            7   dupchk4       3
```

What I have tried to do is make a function that does this and use mapply across both the columns. Here is what the code looks like:

```
             checknum <- function(x,y){
               if(y=x){
                 gsub(x,y,Table2$tobepastedinto)
               }
               else{""}
             }
            mapply(checknum,Table2$Checkfordup,Table1$Checkfordup)
```

The function is taking forever to run in R, and I am pretty sure I'm doing it incorrectly. Does anyone have a better solution for what I'm trying to do? Or is there a better way to use mapply?

EDIT:
Here is the small data set. The NASET has no numbers in it. I want to see if any of mobiles in the Numberset match with those in the NASET and then add the corresponding Number to the NASET, even if the names do not match:

```
 NASET:
 name     Number     mobile
 VAN                 678
 GEORGE              6564
 STEVEN              76787



Numberset:
 name     Number     mobile
 TEU      7          678
 GEGE     6          64
 VEN      5          87
 TETK     7          678

Updated NASET:
NASET:
 name     Number     mobile
 VAN      7          678
 GEORGE              6564
 STEVEN              76787
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
df2$tobepasteinto <- df1$tobecopied[match(df2$Checkfordup, df1$Checkfordup)]
df2$tobepasteinto[is.na(df2$tobepasteinto)] <- ''
```

Or

```
df2$tobepasteinto <-  mapply(function(x,y,z) {indx <- match(x,y)
                          ifelse(is.na(indx), '', z[indx])},
               df2$Checkfordup, list(df1$Checkfordup),list(df1$tobecopied))
```

#### Update

```
  NASET$Number <- Numberset$Number[match(NASET$mobile, Numberset$mobile)]
  NASET$Number[is.na(NASET$Number)] <- ''
  NASET
  #    name Number mobile
  #1    VAN      7    678
  #2 GEORGE          6564
  #3 STEVEN         76787
```

Or

```
  NASET$Number <- mapply(function(x,y,z) {
                     indx <- match(x,y)
                   ifelse(is.na(indx), '', z[indx])},
             NASET$mobile, list(Numberset$mobile), list(Numberset$Number))
```

Or

```
  library(dplyr)
  left_join(NASET[,-2], unique(Numberset[2:3]), by='mobile')
  #   mobile   name Number
  #1    678    VAN      7
  #2   6564 GEORGE     NA
  #3  76787 STEVEN     NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <-  structure(list(tobecopied = c("Copy1", "Copy2", "Copy3"), B = 2:4, 
Checkfordup = c("dupchk1", "dupchk5", "dupchk4"), D = c("5", 
"4", "K")), .Names = c("tobecopied", "B", "Checkfordup", 
"D"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

 df2 <-  structure(list(tobepastedinto = c("", "", "", ""), B = 5:8,
  Checkfordup = c("dupchk1", "dupchk2", "dupchk4", "dupchk4"), 
  D = c("L", "M", "3", "5")), .Names = c("tobepastedinto", 
 "B", "Checkfordup", "D"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

#### newdata

```
  NASET <- structure(list(name = c("VAN", "GEORGE", "STEVEN"), Number = c(NA, 
  NA, NA), mobile = c(678L, 6564L, 76787L)), .Names = c("name", 
  "Number", "mobile"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

 Numberset <- structure(list(name = c("TEU", "GEGE", "VEN", "TETK"),
 Number = c(7L, 6L, 5L, 7L), mobile = c(678L, 64L, 87L, 678L)), .Names =
  c("name", "Number", "mobile"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -4L))
```

Comment: Hey what do I do when the data frames are different lengths? It is giving me an error because of this.

Comment: The error of different lengths in df1 vs df2 still exists. I thought mapply would check each row in df1 vs all rows in df2, so I don't know why the lengths matter

Comment: The error is still persisting with the first piece of code

Comment: the values stored in indx are TRUE or FALSE, not the index of the row. Is that what it is supposed to return?

Comment: Sorry the problem is happening because the df2 has a lot less rows that df1. df1 has 800000 rows while df2 has 400000 rows. SO when the indices are trying to replace in df2, the error im getting is not enough rows in df2

Comment: @VishnuSundaram Okay, I thought it was the opposite.  It will be easier if you provide a small dataset that mimics the original dataset (just like I showed).